# Image upload data empty

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-upload

Currently have these code.

```
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
                $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
                $config['max_size'] = '1000';
                $config['max_width']  = '270';
                $config['max_height']  = '280';
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

Then ill insert the details into the database.

```
$this->Model->upload_image($this->upload->data(),$result_id);
```

But the db row is empty so i checked myself. I `print_r($image_data)` which is the first parameter of the model function. Still empty, to make sure even mor. i typed in.

```
print_r($this->upload->data());
```

Still, the results come out empty.

> Array ( [file_name] => [file_type] => [file_path] => ./uploads/
>   [full_path] => ./uploads/ [raw_name] => [orig_name] => [client_name]
>   => [file_ext] => [file_size] => [is_image] => [image_width] => [image_height] => [image_type] => [image_size_str] => )

EDIT:

```
if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
            $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('view', $error);
            }
            else
            {
            $image_data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
            print_r($this->upload->data());
}
```

Comment: Did you run `$this->upload->do_upload()`?

Comment: I added the do_upload() line of code, although it wont print_r....

Btw, do i need to namem y function do_upload aswell?

Comment: Can you include the view that has the form in your question?

Comment: I just did, on the edit.

Comment: check chat btw. Im still there. left my laptop open all this time.

Comment: Check if form is multipart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have given any **name** to your `input file control` than you must need to set it while using this `do_upload` function.

For e.g.

```
$field_name = "some_field_name";
$this->upload->do_upload($field_name)
```

By default the upload routine expects the file to come from a form field called **userfile**, and the **form must be a "multipart type**

see the reference `$this->upload->do_upload()`

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

under the `Function Reference` in above link

Comment: I was waiting for samutz to post an answer. Ill just accept yours. Thanks for answering!